# JQuery Dialog Box only works once

Tags: jquery, alert

Someone who knows more about JQuery than I do, please let me know why the first dialog box works and the second one doesn't in this test code. Thanks:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
    $txt="This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.";
    $txt2="This is a second box.";?>
<!-- ***** First use ***** -->
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p><?php echo $txt?></p>
    </div>
<!-- ***** Second Use ***** -->
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p><?php echo $txt2?></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: IDs should be unique, you can't have two `id="dialog"`

Answer (score 0):

Id must be unique for Jquery. You have used two same id. So why it's not working. Try with different Id such as id="dialog and second one id="dialog1

Comment: Thanks for that insight. I need to reuse the function Calling it multiple times within the same php page - like as in calling a function with a parameter- is that possible?